# Error running timer ‘ac-update-greedy’: (void-variable org-link-types)

Tags: org-mode, debugging, auto-complete-mode, variables, timers

I very recently updated to Emacs 26.3 and Org 9.2.6, and am getting the above-mentioned error whenever I type "[[" in an org-mode buffer to type a hyperlink. Unsurprisingly, no error after turning off auto-complete mode (20170125.245, the only version I see in "list-packages").

Any possible fixes or recommendations?

**Addendum 1:** Aside from the error message, the link still works fine.

**Addendum 2:** Searching through the variable index of the Org manual, there's no mention of "org-link-types". The second line of the debugger backtrace cites "org-ac--get-link-head-candidates()". The hyperlink takes me to the function's definition in "org-ac.el" where there's a line `(mapcar (lambda (x) (concat x ":")) org-link-types)))`. Is it reasonable to assume this is what's causing the problem? And if so, is there anything to be done about it?

Comment: Check your code (starting with your init file) for that variable. Sounds like it is maybe no longer available/used by Org. First, start Emacs using `emacs -Q`, to see the problem reproduces without your init file. If it doesn't, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Searching through the variable index of the Org manual, there's no mention of "org-link-types". The second line of the debugger backtrace cites "org-ac--get-link-head-candidates()". The hyperlink takes me to the function's definition in "org-ac.el" where there's a line `(mapcar (lambda (x) (concat x ":")) org-link-types)))`. Is it reasonable to assume this is what's causing the problem? And if so, is there anything to be done about it?

Comment: Please add such info to your question, if you think it's relevant to it. Comments can be deleted any time.